# React Native online real-time environment

Tags: react-native, android-emulator

I am new to React Native and I am still struggling with setting up the development environment. Obviously, I went through all the documentation and tried everything suggested. What I'm looking for though is a website/browser-extension service which allows you to work locally in Vscode and run the react-native app and without the need for SDKs or anything else to be able to show the result in the browser in real-time. I tested several online services that you need to deliver your code in a .zip file in order to do this. None of them is actually real-time like expo snack, on the other hand, expo snack is not for dev. Any suggestions (paid and free) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [expo](https://docs.expo.dev/) and [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/)

Expo is way easier to setup than react native and snack.expo.dev ships with an emulator.

Comment: Is there a way to use my machine for development and snack only for real time emulator?